# QShortcut - how to correcly declare in widget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qshortcut

i am trying to use QShortcut, and declare in in widget constructor like:

```
   QShortcut  *keyCtrlL;
    keyCtrlL = new QShortcut(this);
    keyCtrlL->setKey(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_L);
    connect(keyCtrlL, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MyPage::loadB);
```

I am not sure it will work, even it compile fine, as variable is local in the constructor.
So i am trying to declare it as a private variable for the whole class MyPage,

and getting compilation errors:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QWidget *' with an rvalue of type 'MyPage *'
    ui->setupUi(this);
                ^~~~
./qt/forms/ui_mypage.h:69:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'MyPage' here
    void setupUi(QWidget *MyPage)
                          ^
qt/mypage.cpp:153:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'QShortcut'
    keyCtrlL = new QShortcut(this);
```

Even MyPage is inherited from QWidget.
Why this error happens, how can i fix it?

Comment: Please show the class definition for `MyPage` as well as the relevant code at and around the call `ui->setupUi(this);`.

Comment: You may be missing `#include` of MyPage header... Without it, it cannot upcast `MyPage*` to `QWidget*`, check if it is not missing.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile That's so right!! compile now, fine please make your comment as an answer so i can mark it

Comment: @Mira OK, I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing `#include` of `MyPage` header... Without it, it cannot upcast `MyPage*` to `QWidget*`. Check if it is not missing.

Comment: To be presice I forgot #include <QShortcut> in MyPage.h header file, after adding this it worked fine, thanks

Comment: Well, if you keep `QShortcut` by pointer in the `MyPage` class definition (which I bet you do), then you should only forward declare `QShortcut` in `MyPage.h` and `#include` it in `MyPage.cpp`. This is actually the correct way. Including it in the header is not a good practice.

Comment: MyPage.h - what i called header file, sorry is i messed a terminology.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the clarification. `MyPage.h` is a header file. But you should only use `class QShortcut;` (i.e. forward declaration) in that header. And you should only use`#include <QShortcut>` in `MyPage.cpp`.

Comment: I am also not so good in c++ and may be misunderstanding how it works, ^_^ , Initially i added in `MyPage.h` only one string -  `QShortcut  *keyCtrlL;` and it did not compile as described in a question. After adding `#include <QShortcut>` in `MyPage.h` all compiled successfully.

Comment: That is what I am talking about. This works but it is not good solution (for multiple reasons). `#include <QShortcut>` should not be in the header and it should go to `MyPage.cpp`. And to make it compile, you should add `class QShortcut;` (this is so called forward declaration of a class) to the header instead of the include. Read about forward declarations here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c